# How to correctly write a sagemaker tensorflow input_handler() that returns a numpy array?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to implement a input_handler() in inference.py for a sagemaker inference container.

The images/arrays are very big (3D). So I want to pass in a S3 URI, then the input_handler() function should load the image/array from s3 and return the actual numpy array for the model (which expects a tensor):

```
def input_handler(data, context):

    d = data.read().decode('utf-8')

    body = json.loads(d)
    s3path = body['s3_path']

    s3 = S3FileSystem()
    df = np.load(s3.open(s3path))

    return df
```

Returning a numpy array worked with the Sagemaker python api version < 1.0 and input_fn(), but does not work with the new container used by sagemaker python api > 2.0 that expects input_handler().

The actual container image is "763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-inference:1.15-gpu".

During inference, I get the following error in CloudWatch thrown by the container:

```
ERROR:python_service:exception handling request: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 289, in _handle_invocation_post
    res.body, res.content_type = self._handlers(data, context)
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 322, in handler
    response = requests.post(context.rest_uri, data=processed_input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    data=data or 
{}
,
```

What is the correct return type? All examples I found were for json & text...

Comment: return json.dumps({"inputs": [df.tolist()] }) seems to work. But this is very inefficient for large 3d images (converting from np.array to string to tensor). Is there a better solution?

Comment: Still not working, when returning json/tolist() tensorflow returns "Invalid argument: input must be 5-dimensional"

Comment: Ok, remove the extra pair of brackets and the dimensions are right: json.dumps({"inputs": df.tolist() })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

`return json.dumps({"inputs": df.tolist() }).`

Comment: Stiefel, how should we provide input_handler (which converts json to numpy), I am providing like this `model = TensorFlowModel(entry_point='pre_process.py',
                        model_data='s3://...model.tar.gz', framework_version = '2.3.1',role=sagemaker.get_execution_role())` and then I call `model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge')` but it seems that input_handler isnt applying. any way to test it?

Comment: You can do a print("*** Test") in pre_process.py / input_handler(). In Amazon CloudWatch->LogGroups you will find the log for your end point. You can also add "def handler(data, context):" instead of input_handler() and see if this is called.