# How to write a sagemaker tensorflow input_handler() that returns a numpy array?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

Posting it intentionally with a similar caption as this question:
[How to correctly write a sagemaker tensorflow input_handler() that returns a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781356/how-to-correctly-write-a-sagemaker-tensorflow-input-handler-that-returns-a-num)
because the suggested solution doesnt work for me and i have the same problem: my model expects a numpy array but i found no way of giving it to the model.

my input handler in inference.py looks like this:

```
def input_handler(data, context):
    if context.request_content_type == 'application/json':
        decoded_data = data.read().decode('utf-8')
        numpyArr= np.array(decoded_data)
        return json.dumps({"inputs":numpyArr.tolist() })
```

I get the Error message Type:Invalid argument: JSON Value: "..." String is not of expected type: float

Strangely it works without a input handler when i invoke it from a boto3 client:

```
data = np.load("testValues.npy")
payload = json.dumps(data.tolist())
response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,
                                  ContentType='application/json',
                                  Body=payload)
result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
```

Sagemaker version: Version: 2.16.3.post0
TensorFlow ModelServer: 2.2.0-rc2+dev.sha.no_git
TensorFlow Library: 2.2.0